# How to install 0MQ on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I am confused with all the packages `apt-cache` outputs:

```
$ apt-cache search libzmq
libzmq-dbg - lightweight messaging kernel (debugging symbols)
libzmq-dev - lightweight messaging kernel (development files)
libzmq-java - ZeroMQ Java bindings (jzmq)
libzmq-java-doc - Documentation for ZeroMQ Java bindings (jzmq)
libzmq-jni - ZeroMQ Java bindings (jzmq)
libzmq1 - lightweight messaging kernel (shared library)
libzmq3-dev - lightweight messaging kernel (development files)
libzmq5 - lightweight messaging kernel (shared library)
libzmq5-dbg - lightweight messaging kernel (debugging symbols)
libzmqpp-dev - High-level C++ bindings for zeromq3 - development files
libzmqpp3 - High-level C++ bindings for zeromq3
```

libzmq5 is for 0MQ 4.1 stable. So I just install `libzmq5 libzmq5-dbg`? The names are quite confusing. The package description doesn't help at all.

If I would like to install 0MQ 4.1, do I have to also install `libzmq-dbg` and `libzmq-dev`?

Comment: https://tuananh.org/2015/06/16/how-to-install-zeromq-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 6):

1. Download the latest stable release from their [site](http://zeromq.org/intro:get-the-software), which is currently [zeromq-4.2.1.tar.gz](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/releases/download/v4.2.1/zeromq-4.2.1.tar.gz), and extract the files.
2. Make sure you have the packages they require installed.
3. Install `checkinstall` since it is helpful to remove ZMQ later on.
4. Configure, make, install, save the `deb` for later (or don't, up to you).

   ```
   wget https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/releases/download/v4.2.1/zeromq-4.2.1.tar.gz
   tar -xvzf zeromq-4.2.1.tar.gz
   cd zeromq-4.2.1/

   sudo apt-get install libtool pkg-config build-essential autoconf automake uuid-dev
   sudo apt-get install checkinstall

   ./configure
   make
   sudo checkinstall
   sudo ldconfig
   ```

The installation with [checkinstall](https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall) generates a `zeromq_4.2.1-1_amd64.deb` that can be used to remove the package. This is done with `sudo dpkg -r zeromq`.

Comment: Hi Daniel, just a heads up: to format code that is in indented lists, you need 8 spaces, not 4. More specifically, you need 4 spaces *in addition* to whatever indent you already have (so 12 spaces for second level lists etc.).

Comment: @phegde: ZMQ is on the repositories under `libzmq****`, but it is not the latest version. If I'm not mistaken its `libzmq5` for runtime and `libzmq3-dev` for development.

Comment: Yea it's not updated with the latest release. Building it from the tar and installing seems like the only working way right now.